# cant search filter on recyclerview after using load more

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a recycler view that implement load more. but when i add a search filter and sort filter its caused error because of null object reference. this is the error on logcat :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.ilham.obatherbal.herbalJava.herbalModel.getNama()' on a null object reference
```

i want to add a search filter based on name and sort filter based on something.

the search filter actually work before i add load more feature. this is the code on my main activity :

```
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herbal, container, false);
            herbalModels = new ArrayList<>();

            RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
            get20Data();
            sortData(rootView);
            return rootView ;

        }
    private void StartRecyclerView(View rootView) {
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_herbal);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

            // use a linear layout manager
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            // create an Object for Adapter
            mAdapter = new herbalAdapter(mRecyclerView,getActivity(),herbalModels);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore() {
                    //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                    herbalModels.add(null);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(herbalModels.size() - 1);
                    handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //   remove progress item
                            herbalModels.remove(herbalModels.size() - 1);
                            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(herbalModels.size());
                            //add items one by one
                            int start = herbalModels.size();
                            int end = start + 20;
                            loadMore(start,end);

                           }
                    },5000);

                }
            });




        }
private void sortData(final View rootView) {

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filter_herbal);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        List<categoriesHerbal> itemList = new ArrayList<categoriesHerbal>();
        itemList.add(
                new categoriesHerbal(
                        "1",
                        "All"
                )
        );itemList.add(
                new categoriesHerbal(
                        "2",
                        "Jamu"
                )
        );itemList.add(
                new categoriesHerbal(
                        "3",
                        "Kampo"
                )
        );
        ArrayAdapter<categoriesHerbal> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<categoriesHerbal>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemList);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0)
                {
                    StartRecyclerView(rootView);
                    searchData(rootView);

                }
                else
                {
                    categoriesHerbal selectedValue = (categoriesHerbal) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String categories = (String)selectedValue.getCategories();
                    String idCategories = (String )selectedValue.getIdCategories();
                    Log.d(TAG,"selected"+categories+id);
                    categories(idCategories);
                    searchOnCategories(rootView,idCategories);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
private void searchData(View rootView) {
        search = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_herbal);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

    }
 private void filter(String s) {
        ArrayList<herbalModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (herbalModel item : herbalModels){
            if (item.getNama().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))
            {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
        mAdapter.filterlist(filteredList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that item is null. Drop a breakpoint at the for loop and see what's in the herbalModels array. That should point you towards why you have null references in this loop.

```
private void filter(String s) {
        ArrayList<herbalModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (herbalModel item : herbalModels){
            if (item.getNama().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))
            {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
        mAdapter.filterlist(filteredList);
    }
```

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Drop a breakpoint at the for loop declaration and see what's in the herbalModels array, then tell us what you see in memory in the herbalModels array.

Comment: it is null because it didnt load data until the app swipe down (load more) until the end. so what should i do to make data available even tough i didnt  swipe down (load more) until the end. should i make a new array that det all data without load more ?

Comment: oh! sure! preload some data into the original array before loadmore is called, when creating the view perhaps.

Comment: so i'll make a new array beside load more array that get all data and the search filter and spinner filter based on new array that get all data ?